# Android Instrumented Test, Mock Final Classes

Tags: java, android, mockito, powermock, powermockito

How to mock final classes inside Android Instrumented Test cases, that is mocking  final classes inside `Android Run Time`?

(I am using `Mockito 2.X`)

I have a test case like follows -

```
import android.support.test.InstrumentationRegistry;
import android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnit4;
import android.util.Log;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
public class ExampleInstrumentedTest {

    // This is my app specific NON - Final class
    private ShutdownServicesReqSig rebootSig = ShutdownServicesReqSig.newBuilder(ShutDownType.REBOOT_SYSTEM).setReason("test").build();

    private PowerManager mockedPowerManager = null;

    private Context mockedContext = null;


    @Test
    public void testRestart() throws InterruptedException
    {

        mockedContext = Mockito.mock(Context.class);

        mockedPowerManager = Mockito.mock(PowerManager.class);  // Here is the problem android.os.PowerManager is a Final class in latest Android SDK
                                                        // I need to mock it, only then I can use Mockito.verify() on PowerManager

        Mockito.when(mockedContext.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).thenReturn(mockedPowerManager);

        assertTrue(executor.requestShutdown(rebootSig));

        Thread.sleep(1000);

        Mockito.verify(mockedPowerManager).reboot(any(String.class)); // Mocking of PowerManager is essential to be sure of method call on PowerManager, using Mockito.verify 

        Mockito.reset(mockedPowerManager);
    }
}
```

When I am running it as Android Instrumented Test on `ART`(placing inside - `MyApplication\app\src\androidTest`), I am getting following error -

```
org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException:
Cannot mock/spy class android.os.PowerManager
Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
- final classes
- anonymous classes
- primitive types
```

But, the same code, when I am running as a normal JUnit test, inside `JVM` (placing inside - `MyApplication\app\src\test`) it is working perfectly fine.

I need to run it inside `ART`, as I like to test some of my customized Android Services, and I need to mock final classes like `PowerManager`, as only then I can use `Mockito.verify()` on `PowerManager`, to verify certain method calls on `PowerManager`.

Help/guides are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Mockito 2 has an "opt-in" mechanism to enable mocking of final methods or classes, see [here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/What%27s-new-in-Mockito-2#unmockable). You enable it via the mockito extension mechanism by creating the file `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` containing a single line:

```
mock-maker-inline
```

(well, that file needs to be in the class path).

If that works for you, perfect. If not, there is probably nothing else you can do.

You see, instrumenting boils down to: manipulating byte code. Typically, it doesn't work out to use more than one framework doing that.

Meaning: in order to enable that kind of mocking, bytecode needs to be manipulated. And for obvious reasons, getting two **different** bytecode manipulation frameworks to nicely coexist is a very tough challenge.

Long story short: try that extension mechanism, when it doesn't work you have to step back and ask yourself: what exactly is the final goal I intend to achieve?!

Most likely, you probably shouldn't waste your time trying to mock things running within ART.

Comment: This is for text cases running on JVM, not on Android Run Time.
Test cases inside `src/test/resources/` run on JVM, not on ART. 
Same code is already running on JVM.
Challenge is to run it on ART. 
Test cases running on ART are placed inside `src\androidTest`.

Thanks for Architectural/Design guidance. I am also strongly against - trying to mock things running within ART. But, I have some compulsions, that could not be explained here.

Comment: That directory name is just an example. The point is that the mockito framework will check the class path for that specific file. When it finds it, it will enable that feature.

Comment: I have tested, in Mockito 2.X, JUnit test cases, when it is running on JVM, it can mock final classes, even without that config file.

Comment: Which exact version of mockito, which JVM? At least according to their documentation, you still need to ENABLE it manually.

Answer (score 1):

In order to mock and spy final classes & methods in Android Integration tests and Android Instrumentation tests, you need to **only** add the following dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
androidTestImplementation "com.linkedin.dexmaker:dexmaker-mockito-inline-extended:2.28.1"
```

- Make sure to remove any other `mockito` dependency that you are using as an `androidTestImplementation`.
- Also, if you have created a `mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` file, make sure to delete that either.
- This dependecy works for devices running Android P or above.
- Refer to these to links for more details on this dependency: [Link1](https://github.com/linkedin/dexmaker#mocking-final-classes--methods), [Link2](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/mock-final-and-static-methods-on-android-devices-b383da1363ad).

Comment: Do you know if there's another alternative? That library doesn't seem to be maintained since last year, and relies on an older version of mockito.